# Проверить введенную пользователем строку на наличие недопустимых символов

Tags: python

В качестве первого символа допустимы только буквы и знак подчеркивания. Остальные символы могут быть буквами, цифрами и знаком подчеркивания.

Вопрос:как сделать по русски сообщение для первого символа,что не допустимых символов нет,если шаблон регулярного выражения соответствует ему или есть наличие  недопустимых символов,eсли не соответствует.И как вывести этот символ или символы на экран.Для остальных символов также,код моей программы:

```
import re
arr = input("Введите строку:")
text = r'[а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-z_]{1}'
p = arr[0]
d = re.fullmatch(text, p) is not None
print("Первый символ:",d)
m = arr[1:]
text_2 = r'[а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-z0-9_]+'
i = re.fullmatch(text_2,m) is not None 
print("Остальные символы:",i)
```

Comment: В случае несоответствия вы хотите выводить только первый символ, несоответствующий шаблону? Какой должен быть вывод если шаблону несоответствует и первый и ещё какие либо символы из строки или если первый соответствует, но существуют другие несоответствующие?

Comment: Объясню по простому:мы вводим строку,допустим первый символ,у нас 7 программа должна говорить "Первый символ:Недопустимы символ 7",если у нас первый символ буква 'g' то должно быть сообщение "Недопустимых символов нет"

Comment: с остальными символами также

Comment: Можете указать в вопросе необходимый вывод для следующих строк: `['a_str_123', '12_str', '!str_123', '$aaa=']`?

Comment: пользователь должен сам сделать вывод если не допустимые символы или нет если у нас первый допустимый,остальные нет,и остальные допустимые,а первый нет

Comment: я привёл примеры различного ввода пользователем, чтобы понять что вы хотите получить на выходе для разных вариантов... Можете показать вывод для этих 4-х строк?

Comment: a_str_123 вывод:Первый символ:недопустимых символов нет,Остальные символы:недопустимых символов нет.12_str вывод:Первый символ:недопустимый символ '1',остальные символы:нет недопустимых символов,!str_123 вывод:Первый символ:недопустимый символ '!',остальные символы:нет недопустимых символов,$aaa= вывод:не допустимый символ '$',остальные символы:недопустимый символ "="

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def chk_first(s):
    c = s[0]
    if not (c.isalpha() or c=='_'):
        return c
    return None

def chk_rest(s):
    pat = r'([^а-яёa-z_0-9])'
    return re.findall(pat, s[1:], flags=re.I)

def chk_str(s):
    first = chk_first(s)
    print('Первый символ: {}'.format(first if first is not None else 'недопустимых символов нет'))
    rest = chk_rest(s)
    print('Остальные символы: {}'.format(rest if rest else 'недопустимых символов нет'))


s1 = 'a_str_123'
s2 = '12_str'
s3 = '!str_123'
s4 = '$aaa='

for s in [s1, s2, s3, s4]:
    print('Проверяем строку: {}'.format(s))
    chk_str(s)
```

Проверка:

```
Проверяем строку: a_str_123
Первый символ: недопустимых символов нет
Остальные символы: недопустимых символов нет
Проверяем строку: 12_str
Первый символ: 1
Остальные символы: недопустимых символов нет
Проверяем строку: !str_123
Первый символ: !
Остальные символы: недопустимых символов нет
Проверяем строку: $aaa=
Первый символ: $
Остальные символы: ['=']
```